# Is it possible to convert arbitrary length slices to arrays in golang?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, go

Essentially, I need to disallow duplicate values for received data of varying types (i.e. int8(1), then uint32(1) or big.Int(1) is invalid), along the lines of:

```golang
var m map[interface{}]bool

func tryAddValue(value interface{}) {
    switch v := value.(type) {
    // ... other types omitted for brevity
    case *big.Int:
        if v.IsUint64() {
            value = v.Uint64()
        } else if v.IsInt64() {
            value = v.Int64()
        } else {
            bits := v.Bits()
            value = [len(bits)]big.Word(bits)
            //       ^^^ This doesn't compile because it's not a constant
        }
    }
    if m[value] {
        panic(fmt.Errorf("value %v already exists", value))
    }
    m[value] = true
}
```

Since slices cannot be map keys, my only other options for big.Int are string conversion and array conversion, and string conversion is expensive (this code will be on a hot path).

Comment: "Is it possible to convert arbitrary length slices to arrays in [Go]?" No. You have to find an other way to create a map key.

Comment: Even though this could be solved, I'd suggest to hash the slices (the elements) and maintain a set of the hashes. Checking for duplicates in a set of hashes may even be more efficient, not to mention less memory requirement (storing only a hash instead of the whole array/slice).

Comment: "string conversion is expensive" Is it? `hex.EncodeToString(n.Bytes())` takes 125 ns/op on my laptop with an i5 (where n is a big.Int with 10 bytes). And it's not even using hex.Encode, which can avoid allocations. https://go.dev/play/p/c5CML1j9gSR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, reflect to the rescue:

```golang
    bits := v.Bits()
    t := reflect.ArrayOf(len(bits), reflect.TypeOf(bits[0]))
    arr := reflect.New(t).Elem()
    slice := arr.Slice(0, len(bits)).Interface()
    copy(slice.([]big.Word), bits)
    value = arr.Interface()
```

Basic implementation with only integer types https://go.dev/play/p/vOS4exXRkEt

Note: Unless you actually need an actual array, there are faster ways to make map keys. See the comments.

Note2: The above code doesn't take into account the sign. To include sign info, manually encode it as the first word:

```golang
    bits := v.Bits()
    arrLen := len(bits) + 1
    t := reflect.ArrayOf(arrLen, reflect.TypeOf(bits[0]))
    arr := reflect.New(t).Elem()
    slice := arr.Slice(0, arrLen).Interface().([]big.Word)
    slice[0] = big.Word(v.Sign())
    copy(slice[1:], bits)
    value = arr.Interface()
```

https://go.dev/play/p/lKJQJJSENw7

Comment: If you are concerned with performance of string conversion already, I would carefully benchmark this because bringing in reflection incurs significant overhead and this may be even slower

Comment: Yup, converting v.Bytes() to hex string via hex.Encode() or hexEncodeToString() shaves 15% off the runtime vs reflect, and I came up with a custom implementation that runs 30% faster converting v.Bits() to a string. Probably not going to do much better in go since stringifying ends up double-allocting, but with horrible reflect performance these ugly hacks are all we got. Since the question was about converting slice to array, I'm leaving reflection as the answer.

Comment: Actually, the more I think about it, the better the reflect approach feels. String is also an accepted type, which means that I'd need to prefix all encoded strings (including strings themselves) to separate them by "type", which would degrade overall performance since string will happen a lot more often than a big integer.

Comment: Is there a defined size range the `big.Int` could be? If so you could still use a switch block to convert each `big.Int` to the appropriately statically sized array (even with a lot of cases, that might me the most performant)

Comment: Integers are technically unbounded, but that would be a good idea to manually create for up to, say, 5 words. Pushes the slow path so far into the long tail that it no longer matters...